# node-sass doesn't compile newly added scss files

Tags: sass, compilation, node-sass

I'm using "`node-sass": "^4.9.0"` on `linux`. 
Here's my script

```
"sass" : "node-sass assets/scss/main.scss assets/css/style.css --source-map assets/css/style.css.map -w"
```

It compiles scss files fine. But whenever I add a new scss file on one of my scss folders it doesn't compile that file anymore. I need to write the npm run command again and restart it.

I also tried following commands...

```
"sass" : "node-sass assets/scss/ -o assets/css/ --source-map assets/css/style.css.map -w"

"sass" : "node-sass assets/scss/ assets/css/ --source-map assets/css/style.css.map --watch --recursive"

"sass" : "node-sass assets/scss/ assets/css/ --source-map assets/css/style.css.map -w --recursive"
```

But they don't work. Can anybody help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this?

```
node-sass assets/scss/**/*.scss -o assets/css/ --source-map assets/css/style.css.map -w
```

Nothe the `assets/scss/**/*.scss` that is thelling to get all files in any folder inside `scss/` with the file type `.scss`.